# ¿Puedo saber con SendGrid si un correo llega o no a su destinatario cuando lo envio?

Tags: c#, .net

```
        var client = new SendGridClient(this.apiKey);

        var from = new EmailAddress(_from);
        var subject = _subject;
        var to = new EmailAddress(_to);
        var plainTextContent = _plainTextContent;
        var htmlContent = _htmlContent;
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Envio el correo utilizanzo la libreria de **SendGrid** con c#. 
¿Se puede utlizar la libreria para que una vez se envie se obtenga respuesta si llego el correo o algo paso (no existe correo)?

PD: Lo de saber si esta en la lista de SendGrid no me sirve, necesito es una vez e envie el correo y  no hacer dos peticiones para consultar dicha lista.

Comment: Existe un servicio que si pagas 5 dolares mensuales adicionales, puedes consumir su API para revisar la actividad de mails https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages

Answer (score 2):

Sí se puede pero no directamente desde tu envío, ellos te reportan los eventos por un POST, es decir debes crear un EndPoint que reciba ese POST, ahí mismo en su página tienen un botón donde pones tu URL y puedes probar con un ejemplo que te envían.

https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/mail_settings

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el json que te envían de ejemplo donde viene el tipo de evento

```
[{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "processed",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "ZVi3_VSzK015oIYdynYgEQ==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0"
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "deferred",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "fDoij-hAjVx8xOQvh2gb3A==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "response": "400 try again later",
    "attempt": "5"
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "delivered",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "aoIheLGPJOrEobVrCo3L8g==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "response": "250 OK"
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "open",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "y6zxWDMzNKpe2fcVLZ1K7A==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "useragent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)",
    "ip": "255.255.255.255"
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "click",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "wdMAd5gRmmQJxYEP7HN1fw==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "useragent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)",
    "ip": "255.255.255.255",
    "url": "http://www.sendgrid.com/"
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "bounce",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "Lr8M9TpuvKBn7lWQllHeZg==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "reason": "500 unknown recipient",
    "status": "5.0.0"
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "dropped",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "sqZZ6dpAZ_3voL0_v2BQkg==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "reason": "Bounced Address",
    "status": "5.0.0"
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "spamreport",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "QP8bGoU0HzNZd0XnVMw0VQ==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0"
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "unsubscribe",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "mNHkKKWQfwnTMpCuByNwqg==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0"
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "group_unsubscribe",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "2QSHciT_oAuL_qh2eg2cKw==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "useragent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)",
    "ip": "255.255.255.255",
    "url": "http://www.sendgrid.com/",
    "asm_group_id": 10
},
{
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1529499943,
    "smtp-id": "u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555u003e",
    "event": "group_resubscribe",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "pWf-D5yw3or_ZuWMxQuZkQ==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "useragent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)",
    "ip": "255.255.255.255",
    "url": "http://www.sendgrid.com/",
    "asm_group_id": 10
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Me temo que no se puede ya que el servicio se basa en `SMTP`

Lo mas aproximado que puedes hacer es enviar un link en el mail que recibe el usuario para que al presionarlo ingrese a alguna pagina que desarrolles y lance el proceso de validacion de la recepcion del mail

Esto se utiliza mucho en las validaciones de registro

Para realizar esto deberias hostear un sitio web en donde desarrolles una pagina que envies en el mail, podria ser algo como

```
http:\\sitio\RecepticionMail?token=xxx
```

junto a la url deberias poner un token encriptado que recibas y puedas recuperar los datos del usuario que recibio el mail